macOS keeps asking my ssh passphrase with git remote since I updated to Sonoma
Referencing this similar issue, which had good suggestions:
macOS keeps asking my ssh passphrase since I updated to Sierra
but this solution isn't working for Sonoma, and using git on a server. Used the following in .ssh/config:
AddKeysToAgent yes
UseKeychain yes

I removed the ssh key and started over - also tried the following:
ssh-add --apple-use-keychain ~/.ssh/id_rsa

is there some identity requirement here?

What finally worked for me on macOS Sonoma was this:
~/.ssh/config:
Host *
  IgnoreUnknown UseKeychain
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Then running these commands separately:
ssh-add --apple-use-keychain ~/.ssh/id_rsa
ssh-add --apple-load-keychain ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Oh, and if you have openssh installed, uninstall that or these commands will fail.
